# MySQL queries not being executed sequentially (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I need to execute a series of MySQL inserts in a loop, and then do something after they are all completed. However, I'm not sure where to put the callback --

```
for (var q=0; q<things.length; q++)
{

thing
    .create({
        active_time: time
        rule: rule
        next: next_object,
        percentage: object.percent,
        enabled: 1,
    })
    .complete(function(err, newSchedule) {
        console.log('thing added successfully');

    })

}
```

I can't put it in the .`complete` section, because it needs to occur after all of them. How can I ensure that they are all done before proceeding?

*EDIT:* I've started using AsyncJS but it seems that the MySQL queries will callback before they are finished. Here is the new code:

```
if (valid) {

        async.each(arrayOfObjects, tools.submitThing, function()
        {
            console.log("finished submissions")
        });
```

and

```
exports.submitThing = function(thingObject, callback) {

   thing
    .create({
        active_time: time
        rule: rule
        next: next_object,
        percentage: object.percent,
        enabled: 1,
    })
    .complete(function(err, newSchedule) {
        console.log('thing added successfully');

    })

    callback();

}
```

The server console shows that the message "submissions completed" registers before the MySQL insertions. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an asynchronous control flow library to handle executing a loop of asynchronous functions in order.

Check out the `async` npm module ([docs](https://github.com/caolan/async)) and especially the `async.eachSeries` function. This will let you loop over all of your `things`, and for each `thing`, run the create queries one-by-one. You'll then have a final callback function at the very end when they're all done inserting.

Comment: I tried this, but it seemed to me that the MySQL queries would start the operation and callback immediately, even if they hadn't finished. Is this the case?

Comment: Call `callback()` inside of the `.complete` function instead of outside of it, then you should be good to go.
`.complete(function(err, newSchedule) {
 console.log('thing added successfully');
 callback();
}`